# Rename a file in a folder based on presence of another file

Tags: shell-script, find, rename

The scenario I currently have is, I have multiple folders and each folder has traffic type (like ftp.csv, http.csv etc) and metrics (cpu.csv and memory.csv).

folder1>
cpu.csv 
http.csv

folder2>
cpu.csv
ftp.csv

As the metrics file is of same name across all folders , say, cpu.csv, I want to rename cpu.csv in the folder containing ftp.csv to cpu_ftp.csv and in the folder of http.csv, I want to move cpu.csv into cpu_http.csv

I want to move like the following
folder1>
cpu_http.csv 
http.csv

Please help me in achieving in bash script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ***bash***:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in /folder[0-9]*
do
    type=""   # traffic type (either `http` or `ftp`)
    if [ -f "$d/ftp.csv" ]; then     # check if file `ftp.csv` exists within a folder
        type="ftp"
    elif [ -f "$d/http.csv" ]; then  # check if file `http.csv` exists within a folder
        type="http"
    fi
    # if `traffic type` was set and file `cpu.csv` exists - rename the file
    if [ ! -z "$type" ] && [ -f "$d/cpu.csv" ]; then
        mv "$d/cpu.csv" "$d/cpu_$type.csv"
    fi        
done
```

Comment: The solution works fine if the folder names are in sequence. But the names that I have are like the following.    TC0000_StabilityAccess_Testsuite-2017-06-05-001942/
TC0000_Stability_Testsuite-2017-06-05-025024/
TC0000_Stability_Testsuite-2017-06-05-045954/
TC0000_Stability_Testsuite-2017-06-05-054305/
so, no way to replace "d"

Comment: @KarthickM, so, have you tried to specify `for d in /TC0000_Stability*` ?

Comment: I tried as you said earlier, the script looks like the following now            for d in /TC0000_Stability*
do
    type=""  
    if [ -f "$d/http.csv" ]; then     # check if file `ftp.csv` exists within a folder
        type="http"
    elif [ -f "$d/ftp.csv" ]; then  # check if file `http.csv` exists within a folder
        type="ftp"
    fi
    # if `traffic type` was set and file `cpu.csv` exists - rename the file
    if [ ! -z "$type" ] && [ -f "$d/cpu*.csv" ]; then
        mv "$d/cpu*.csv" "$d/cpu_$type.csv"
    fi
done
But still it doesn't do a move. No errors thrown

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -name cpu.csv -exec sh -c '
   for f
   do
      [ -f ${f%/*}/http.csv ] && { mv "$f" "${f%.???}_http.csv"; :; } \
                      || \
      [ -f  ${f%/*}/ftp.csv ] &&   mv "$f" "${f%.???}_ftp.csv"
   done
' sh {} +
```

---

We setup a `find` command which looks for `files` recursively from the current dir onwards and which have the name `cpu.csv` and collect and send the names collected in a bunch to the `sh` command. Inside `sh` we setup a `for` loop which shall iterate over the command line arguments to the `sh` and look for the presence of the `http.csv` in which case the cpu.csv shall be renamed to cpu_http.csv. Similarly for the other case.